# How to calculate the evaluation metrics on streaming data for online ML algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation, online-algorithms, sequence-analysis

I am working on a binary classification problem where I need to develop an online ML model that can work on streaming data. However, I am not sure how can I use the evaluation metrics for classification such as precision, recall and F-score to evaluate the performance of the model on the streaming data.

One way that I found was that we can apply a sliding window and calculate the evaluation metrics per window. Then, we calculate the final results for all windows. I am not sure if this is a naive way to do it and there is more advance way to do it.

**Note**, we **assume** the data arrive sequential in streaming manner, which it is different from batch settings where we have all the data in advance. This requires us to calculate the evaluation metrics according to the streaming settings.

Comment: Look up the loss/risk functions used in online learning/bandit problems. That may be useful. You could compare excess online risk of the online learner relative to an oracle learner that uses all the data to train from the get go. I think this is close to your sliding window idea.